# How to split string in Rails with pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, split

I've a string like this "some text !11.22.33" and when i call

```
"some text !11.22.33".scan(/!(\w+)/)[0].join.to_s
```

it returns only "11". 
I want to return "11.22.33" so scan function has to skip dot and take all the string. How i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is always in this format, just use

```
"some text !11.22.33".partition('!').last
```

For a regex approach, you may use matching with capturing:

```
"some text !11.22.33"[/!([\d.]+)/, 1]
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/ZmhIZ3)

**Details**:

- `!` - a literal `!` symbol
- `([\d.]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits or dots
- The `1` argument tells Ruby to output only the captured value

An alternative regex is [`/!(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)/`](http://rubular.com/r/y9CWXZTqNL) that will capture 1+ digits and then 0 or more  sequences of a `.` and 1+ digits (so, if there is a trailing dot, it won't be captured).

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: If the digits and dots are always in the known format at the end the string, you may use `rpartition` instead of `partition`: `"some text !11.22.33".rpartition('!').last`